# multithreading, id doesnt work, how to add other function

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm getting bad id from every thread, how Can i get a right id ? And I must create one more thread like marshal who allows deputy saing, how i can solve this problem ? I'm using rostrum as monitor to locking or unlocking mutex which allow to have access for only one thread.

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>

typedef enum
{ false = 0, true } t_bool;

pthread_mutex_t mutex;
int rostrum;
rostrum = 0;

void *
deputy (void *arg)
{
  int tid = (int *) arg;
  printf ("Deputy no: %d in f() \n", tid);  // ??? no.1

  int SAID;
  SAID = 0;

  while (SAID == 0)
    {
      pthread_mutex_trylock (&rostrum);
      if (rostrum == 0)
      {
          rostrum = 1;
          printf ("\t Deputy no: %d is saing\n", tid);
          SAID = 1;
      }
      pthread_mutex_unlock (&rostrum);
    }
}

int
main ()
{
  pthread_t tid;
  int i = 0;
  for (i; i < 20; i++)
    {
        /* spurious characters deleted here */
        printf ("Deputy no: %d before f().\n", i);  // ??? no.2
        pthread_create (&tid, NULL, deputy, &tid);
    }
}
```

Results:

```
    Deputy no: 0 before f()
    Deputy no: 1 before f()
    Deputy no: 2 before f()
    Deputy no: -863940960 inf f() 
    Deputy no: -863940960 inf f() 
 Deputy no: -863940960 is saing
 Deputy no: -863940960 is saing
    Deputy no: 3 before f()
    Deputy no: -863940960 inf f() 
    Deputy no: 4 before f()
    Deputy no: -863940960 inf f() 
 Deputy no: -863940960 is saing
    Deputy no: 5 before f()
    Deputy no: -863940960 inf f() 
 Deputy no: -863940960 is saing
    Deputy no: 6 before f()
    Deputy no: 7 before f()
    Deputy no: -863940960 inf f() 
    Deputy no: 8 before f()
    Deputy no: -863940960 inf f() 
 Deputy no: -863940960 is saing
    Deputy no: 9 before f()
    Deputy no: 10 before f()
    Deputy no: 11 before f()
    Deputy no: -863940960 inf f() 
 Deputy no: -863940960 is saing
 Deputy no: -863940960 is saing
 Deputy no: -863940960 is saing
    Deputy no: 12 before f()
    Deputy no: -863940960 inf f() 
    Deputy no: -863940960 inf f() 
 Deputy no: -863940960 is saing
    Deputy no: -863940960 inf f() 
    Deputy no: -863940960 inf f() 
 Deputy no: -863940960 is saing
    Deputy no: 13 before f()
 Deputy no: -863940960 is saing
 Deputy no: -863940960 is saing
    Deputy no: 14 before f()
    Deputy no: -863940960 inf f() 
    Deputy no: -863940960 inf f() 
 Deputy no: -863940960 is saing
 Deputy no: -863940960 is saing
    Deputy no: 15 before f()
    Deputy no: -863940960 inf f() 
    Deputy no: 16 before f()
    Deputy no: -863940960 inf f() 
 Deputy no: -863940960 is saing
 Deputy no: -863940960 is saing
    Deputy no: -863940960 inf f() 
    Deputy no: 17 before f()
    Deputy no: 18 before f()
    Deputy no: -863940960 inf f() 
    Deputy no: -863940960 inf f() 
 Deputy no: -863940960 is saing
    Deputy no: 19 before f()
 Deputy no: -863940960 is saing
 Deputy no: -863940960 is saing
```

Comment: Why are you pointing all your threads at one tid var that, anyway, probably no longer exists because main() has returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fetch a thread's PThread-id from within the thread itself use `pthread_self()`.

To do so modify the threas function like this:

```
void *
deputy (void * arg)
{
  pthread_t ptid = pthread_self();
  ...
```

If you really want to store the PThread-id of each thread created in the main thread **and** pass down it's reference, you need to provide variables for each, like so:

```
int
main (void)
{
  pthread_t ptid[20];

  {
    size_t i = 0;
    for (; i < 20; ++i)
    {
      printf ("Deputy no: %zu before f().\n", i); 
      pthread_create (&ptid[i], NULL, deputy, &ptid[i]);
    }
  }

  /* Make sure main does not end before all threads ended, 
     as they make use of ptid[] which lives on main's stack. */
  {
    size_t i = 0;
    for (; i < 20; ++i)
    {
      pthread_join(ptid[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

---

Also please note that when passing down the address of a `pthread_t` typed variable, the thread function shall also use it as such, like here:

```
void *
deputy (void *arg)
{
  pthread_t ptid = *((pthread_t *) arg);
  ...
```

---

Also^2 `pthread_t` is opaque. So it's representation is implementation defined. If can be an integer or a pointer or ...  - so how to print if depended on the specific implementation of the PThread library used.

Comment: It's working, ok. But How can I solve problem with marshal ? TO invite deputy for speaking ? 

Like:

 
      wantToSay();
      listeningOther();
      speaking();
 

 
      While (1)
      {
      invite_deputy[no]; //marshal invite deputy
      }

with class Monitor

Comment: @kxyz: I'm sry I have to state I do not get your requirement. They seem to not be related to the code you showed.

Comment: @kxyz: If this answered your question please mark it as such by clicking the answer's check mark. If you liked the answer feel free to also upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

In your `main()` you have

```
pthread_t tid;
```

which you do not initialise, so its contents are undefined.

You pass a pointer to this as your argument on `pthread_create` here:

```
pthread_create (&tid, NULL, deputy, &tid);
```

I think that you are hoping that you specifying `&tid` as the first parameter to `pthread_create` will overwrite the value in `tid`. However, there are two problems with this. Firstly, you have no guarantee when it will happen - the `printf` could already have run in the new thread. The second is that a subsequent call to `pthread_create` could overwrite this value, i.e. you could run two `pthread_create` calls before the `printf` in the first is executed.

Then use this as your thread's 'id'.

```
int tid = (int *) arg;
printf ("Deputy no: %d in f() \n", tid);  // ??? no.1
```

This will in essence print the same undefined value in every thread.

If you want to get a unique thread ID, use `pthread_self`, rather than looking at the argument passed and attempting to pass as an argument the result of the `pthread_create` call.